# Mongodb keeps crashing every few minutes

Tags: mongodb

I have been using Mongodb for about 1 year now, both on windows and linux. Unfortunately, In the last few days, I have been experiencing a weird problem with it. The Mongodb server stops within few minutes of starting in my local machine. I have a site in production(on AWS servers with Ubuntu) but that seems to be working okay. In my PC I have windows 10, 64bit, and installed 64bit Mongodb version 3.6 of the community server. I have Googled and tried to apply most of the solutions given, none is working. Here are a few things I have tried.

1. Deleting all the contents of data/db folder (this is to encompass all the solutions given to delete a few specific files in this folder. I deleted it all just to make sure)
2. Uninstalled and installed multiple times,both versions of Mongodb (3.6 and 3.4), each installed at a time, (just to make sure its not a specific version that has this issue).

After each 'cleansing', the issue persists.
And what is happening, after each crash, the mongod.exe file is being deleted. This is forcing me to take the installation file and running it so that I can use the repair option to repair the installation. Then the mongod.exe file gets created again. I have done this more than 10 times and Am getting frustrated.
When I do a clean install, here is a screenshot of the last few logs in the cmd before it crashes:
[image]

Then after it crashes I do a repair using the installation file, and the logs below shows the messages I get:
[image]

Does anyone has any idea what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: Please don't post Images of screens containing "text" here. Select the text from the output and post that here instead. There was a reason why your account could not post images up to this point, and that was to teach you that lesson. Also "Crashing" and not "Crushing" when you edit your question. But there are some other things to pay attention to as well.

Comment: I don't see any error in the log. You appear to just be running the instances directly from the command line and not as a service, so are you completely certain that you just don't have something sending keystrokes ( i.e `Ctrl+C` ) to the open window and ending the process? Without a "FATAL" in the log it would appear something else is terminating the process at any rate.

Comment: Do you have and antivirus activated? Have you seen the antivirus logs? It looks like a 3rd entity (software) is crashing the mongod service and the .exe deleted looks like antivirus action, maybe you updated your antivirus and for some reason it is stoping and crashing mongod. Regards,

Comment: @HectorMartinez ..It could be viruses. About 3 days ago I deleted my antivirus because of too many ads and stuff, then the next day I went online and installed some free software which turned out to be a disaster. It installed cryptocurrency mining apps and other viruses that I have been trying to eliminate. I have just reinstalled the antivirus, and scanned the system which cleaned everything, and after a reboot, the mongodb server has been up for more than 10 mins now, which is longer than it has been the last few days. It definitely is a virus that used to close the server. Thanks so much.